# Static instance name SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My SQL Server Management Studio can't detect my LocalDB, every time I start my computer I have to run the code below in my Prompt.

```
SqlLocalDb.exe start
SqlLocalDb.exe i MSSQLLocalDB
```

Then in every run I get a different instance like: `np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#E4E2BD8D\tsql\query`

I'd like a static instance name and stop running a .bat file just to have access to my databases. I know there's a way to do it but I still didn't find any solution.

**UPDATE**

For those who are testing the command, I run it inside the following folder:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\(version)\Tools\Binn
```

(version): your version, mine is 110 (v11.0)

Comment: Did you try (localdb)\v11.0 (put in the correct version) as server name?

Comment: @sepupic yes I did, it says the server was not found.

Comment: Then you can try to create it with this name (or any other name) and then start it

Comment: That's what I'm asking, the last tutorial I tried to follow was this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-an-alternate-pipe

Comment: No, that is different. You have no full edition of SQL Server, you use localdb. I asked if you tied to first create, and then start an instance with YOUR name: SqlLocalDB.exe create "MyLocalDB" SqlLocalDB.exe start "MyLocalDB"

Comment: But this'd be the same as I'm doing, I still have to start it and get the pipe name to use in my connection. I've done what you suggested.

Comment: I understood that you want to use static name, so I suggested you to first create the instance with name that you want and then USE THIS NAME, and not the pipe(that is different every time you start the instance)

Comment: Onced created, use this instance name in your connection string, the instance provided in your connection string will start without need to be started with  SqlLocalDB.exe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156500/discussion-between-thadeu-fernandes-and-sepupic).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have fixed a similar issue I had. Run Services.msc as an admin, look for your SQL Server instance in the list of services (eg- 'SQL Server (LocalDB)'), right-click and go to Properties, and from there you can change Startup type to 'Automatic'.

Comment: I couldn't find this exact service, here is a list of services that I found in my Services.msc related to SQL Server https://prnt.sc/gw51ro

Comment: Unnamed instances are called 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)' in the services. Try that one.